# Add a QTextureMaterial to a custom mesh

Tags: qt, qt3d

I have a custom mesh (created in blender) that I insert into Qt3D using the following code:

```
 QMesh *mesh = new QMesh(rootEntity);
 mesh->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(baseUrl+"mesh.obj"));
```

This works fine; I can add it to an entity with a material and everything.

Then I create a custom material using a texture loaded from a `.png`. I do this using the following code:

```
Qt3DRender::QTextureLoader *loader = new Qt3DRender::QTextureLoader(rootEntity);
Qt3DExtras::QTextureMaterial *material = new Qt3DExtras::QTextureMaterial(rootEntity);
loader->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(baseUrl+"pattern.jpg"));
material->setTexture(loader);
```

This also works fine. When I add this material to a built-in Qt mesh (e.g. `QPlaneMesh` or `QSphereMesh`) it shows perfectly on the surface as one would expect.

However - now comes the problem - if I add it with the QMesh specified above, the mesh just gets one homogeneous color which seems to be the average over the colors in the pattern. Here you can see what I mean: both objects have the same material. The top one is inserted externally while the bottom one is a `QPlaneMesh`.

[image]

Can someone explain me why that is the case? And is there a way to successfully add textures to custom meshes?

Note: I have tried this with 2D and 3D meshes and it is the same outcome.

Note 2: I have also tried it with diferent images and it still just gets one homogeneous average color.

UPDATE: I tried (following the suggestion in the answer) to add a texture attribute to the geometry of my imported mesh like the following:

```
Qt3DCore::QEntity *entity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);
QMesh *mesh = new QMesh(entity);
mesh->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(baseUrl+"mesh.obj"));

const int stride = (3 + 2 + 3 + 4) * sizeof(float);
QSize resolution = QSize(2,2);
const int nVerts = resolution.width() * resolution.height();
QAttribute *texCoordAttr = new QAttribute(mesh->geometry());
Qt3DRender::QBuffer *vertexBuffer = new Qt3DRender::QBuffer(mesh->geometry());
texCoordAttr->setName(QAttribute::defaultTextureCoordinate1AttributeName());
texCoordAttr->setVertexBaseType(QAttribute::Float);
texCoordAttr->setVertexSize(2);
texCoordAttr->setAttributeType(QAttribute::VertexAttribute);
texCoordAttr->setBuffer(vertexBuffer);
texCoordAttr->setByteStride(stride);
texCoordAttr->setByteOffset(3*sizeof(float));
texCoordAttr->setCount(nVerts);
vertexBuffer->setDataGenerator(QSharedPointer<PlaneVertexBufferFunctor>::create(1.0f,1.0f,resolution, false));   //these input values (width, height, resolution, mirrored) are probably the cause of the problem

mesh->geometry()->addAttribute(texCoordAttr);   //it crashes here
entity->addComponent(mesh);
entity->addComponent(transform);
entity->addComponent(material);
```

I created the functor for `setDataGenerator` like in the `QPlaneMesh` code. Now I am suspecting the segmentation fault is because of sizing mismatch. So how can I get the correct width and height of an external mesh from its `QGeometry`? And what else might be wrong here?

Comment: I think I might have confused something here and disregarded that you want to load the mesh from a file. I thought you wanted to create it yourself in code which would have made it easy to add texture coordinates. In this case you should probably add the texture coordiantes you want to you obj file directly. Otherwise, if you want to do it in code, you have to create a new buffer that uses the vertices of the loaded mesh and inserts the proper texture coordinates.

Comment: When you look at the file, does it contain the key `vt` somewhere? This indicates texture coordinates in a obj file.

Comment: @FlorianBlume what do you mean with "look at the file"? when I open it I see the 3D object

Comment: No I mean open it with a text editor ;) It's a plain text file that follows a certain format. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file).

Comment: I edited my answer, this should probably help you more than before ;) Let me know if you are able to solve this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the mesh is missing the texture coordinates. When you open the file with a text editor, do you see the key `vt` somewhere? Those are the texture coordinates. You can read about the format [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file).

If you still want the obj file that you have, you have to add texture coordinates if it doesn't have any. It's probably best to open the file in Blender and use its texture mapper - at least for more complex meshes. Guessing which vertex needs which texture coordinate is not really feasible.

The texture coordinates work as follows:
If you have an image of, say 500 by 400 pixels, the texture coordinate (0.7, 0.3) is (500 * 0.7, 400 * 0.3) = (350, 120), meaning that the vertex which has that texture coordinate will receive the color value of the pixel at (350, 120). Values inside a triangle will get interpolated.

If your obj file comes along with a mtl file then it probably already has texture coordinates. If you want to load this mtl file use the [QSceneLoader](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qsceneloader.html) and add it to its parent `QEntity` to display everything.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for explaining the concept. I do indeed have a plane, do you know if and how I can access its texture coordinates? Or do I have to create it from scratch to modify these parameters? 
(and it should be `createPlaneVertexData`^^)

Comment: Whoops, you are right of course with the name of the function :D You have to add the parameters yourself, like they do in the class. If you look at the [header file](https://github.com/qt/qt3d/blob/5.11/src/extras/geometries/qplanegeometry.h) of the implementation, you will se this line `Q_PROPERTY(Qt3DRender::QAttribute *texCoordAttribute READ texCoordAttribute CONSTANT)`. So you can't access them as long as you haven't created them.

Comment: You need to add a `QAttribute` for the texture coordinates to the header file of your custom mesh and fill it in the implementation of the header with the respective texture coordinates.

Comment: Just as you were editing your answer, I managed to add the texture coordinates in blender! So now it is working!! Thank you so much!

Comment: and wait, I didn't know QSceneLoader was able to load .mtl files! All the time I have been creating the materials myself thinking it wasn't possible to import them.. but good to know! you learn as you go!